# Clear i to 0 bits

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

I'm working through Cracking the Coding Interview and one of the bit manipulations techniques is as follows:

> To clear all bits from i through 0 (inclusive), we take a sequence of all 1s (which is -1) and shift it left by i + 1 bits. This gives us a sequence of 1s (in the most significant bits) followed by i 0 bits.

```
int clearBitsIthrough0(int num, int i){
    int mask = (-1 << (i + 1));
    return num & mask;
}
```

How is -1 a sequence of all 1s?

Comment: The quote assumes a [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation

Comment: Consider what would happen if you incremented "all ones". `x + 1 = 0` should mean that `x = -1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using C/C++, `int` represents a signed 32-bit integer represented with [two's complement](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

`-1` by itself is assumed to be of type `int`, and therefore is equivalent to `0xFFFFFFFF`. This is derived as follows:

`1` is `0x00000001`. Inverting the bits gives `0xFFFFFFFE`, and adding one yields the two's complement representation of `-1`: `0xFFFFFFFF`, a sequence of 32 ones.

Comment: If you don't mind a follow up: Why is 1 being added to i? I'm working through a simple of case of i = 1 and 1 bit shift seems to be all you need to get that 1 bit cleared, but this formula would have you shift two.

Comment: @EternalStudent If i=1, the goal is to clear bits 1 to 0. I guess Gayle is zero-indexing the bits starting from the LSB (least significant bit). `-1 << 2` would result in thirty ones then two zeroes, and when those two zeroes are AND'ed, they clear the lowest two bits (1 to 0) in `num`.

Answer (score 0):

You have: int mask = (-1 << (i - 1));
Seems you are missing a cast:

```
int mask = ((int)-1 << (i - 1));
```